# lookup field from diff data source

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to fill a lookup field from a list in parent site and subsite in the same web application?

Is it possible to fill a lookup field from a list in parent site and subsite in the different web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With out code you 1st question is possible. Create a content type at the root site and the list you want the data to be looked up from. Create the look up column in the content type. Now add that content type to any child web list. the lookup values will be pulled from the root web list.

2nd question is not without code.